# Fetching Data for active session user in php msqli

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PHP but working on this below. If I specify the email address, it will fetch the orders of the particular email address but I want it to pick the email address of the active session user and fetch the orders of the user. How do I work around this? Hoping to get helped.

```
<?php
require("db.php");
error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

    $stmt=$db->prepare("select * from user where email=email");
    $stmt->execute(array('email'=>$_SESSION['email']));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count=$stmt->rowCount();
?>

<tbody>
 <?php
 $email = $_SESSION['email'];
$query=$db->query('select * from sellorder where email = "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"');
while($roww=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["orderno"].'</span>'; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["date"].'</span>'; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["btcvalue"].'</span>'; ?></td>
   <td>$<?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["usdvalue"].'</span>'; ?></td>
   <td>₦<?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["nairavalue"].'</span>'; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo '<span class="text-dark">'.$roww["accountno"].'</span>'; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo '<span class="text-success">'.$roww["status"].'</span>'; ?></td> 
 </tr>
   <?php
     }
 ?>
              </tbody>
```

Comment: Side note: you do this assignment twice: `$email = $_SESSION['email'];` but then never use the variable in the code we see. You should definitely delete the second one, and also delete the first one if you're just going to use `$_SESSION['email']` directly.

Comment: You should use prepared statements for all your queries, not just some.

Comment: please try changing your where condition to this  `where email= :email`

then  `$stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$_SESSION['email']));`

Answer (score 1):

You're not using placeholders correctly in the first query. You're asking for all records where the `email` column equals the `email` column. It should be:

```
"select * from user where email=:email"
```

The second one does not have a placeholder at all which is a huge mistake. **Always use placeholder values**:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('select * from sellorder where email = :email');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $_SESSION['email']]);

while($roww=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: Thanks all. I tried all suggestion but still not fetching any data. I thought the simpliest way to go about it is. I have 2 tables - USER table and SELLORDER table. The two tables are not linked but in same DB. Both USER and SELLORDER tables have email columns. I want to fetch the fetch the session user's data where his email in the USER table is same with SELLORDER table.

Comment: Don't use things like "email" as a foreign key. Instead use an `AUTO_INCREMENT`-type ID column as your key. Email addresses can and will change. They're also arbitrary strings that are a lot more "expensive" to index than compact integer values. You want primary and foreign keys to be *immutable* and *never recycled*.

Comment: How do I go about that please?